# Can "another" be used as a subject?

Tags: pronouns, subjects

> For example, there are two groups of people, a group travels to a
>   foreign country just to enjoy beautiful attractions  or take part in
>   interesting festivals, and **another** goes to a new place to
>   experience its culture, history.

Is the use of "another" in this sentence correct?

Comment: Do dictionaries mention a pronoun usage? Does looking up "another was" in a Google search give any pointers?

Comment: Bartender!  I'll have another.

Comment: By the way, I don't drink and down vote.

Comment: Another might avoid giving a direct answer to your question, Larry, but I won't: The use of _another_ as a subject in your example sentence is fine. The sentence as a whole, however, is too long and sounds run-on. I recommend replacing the comma after _people_ with a period, and replacing the _a_ before _group_ with _One_. I would also remove the comma after _culture_ and add the word _and_ between _culture_ and _history_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking if it is correct to use *another* in the sentence. It is not correct. The word ***another*** is

> used to refer to a different person or thing from one already mentioned or known about: [AS PRONOUN] *moving from one place to another*

In your sentence, there are only two groups of people. If you want to mean ***alternative of two***, you have to use ***the other*** in place of *another*.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]